# Why is my AMD Phenom 2 X6 1090T overheating?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I got an old AMD rig from a friend to help him fix issues with overheating.

Here are the specs

CPU: Phenom 2 X6 1090T
Cooler: Scythe ??
Mobo: Asrock 870 Extreme3
RAM: 2x4GB DDR3 (Corsair , 1333 Mhz)
GPU: GTX560

What I did so far:
1. Took the system apart, changed thermal paste, put it back together
2. Fresh Windows 8.1 install
3. Ran prime95 (passed all tests)

No overheating up to this point. Just when I thought the issues were fixed, I stumbled into a number of weird behaviours.

1. While trying to Upgrade to Windows 10, the system closed down due to overheating (tried this twice).
2. When starting the system from a "cold" state directly into the bios, I could watch the temperature literally climb degree by degree in the hardware monitor. Temperatures went up into the high 80 degrees Celsius range before I shut down the computer.

Bios CPU fan setting is set to "full on" but the fan doesn't really seem to care. It constantly cycles between ramping up and slowing down. Bios shows RPM numbers of barely more than 500. Unfortunately I have no fitting AM3 cpu cooler available for testing here.

At this point, I am not sure what the next steps would be to figure this problem out. In fact, this raised a number of questions...

How is it possible that my CPU heats up when monitoring it in the Bios? This shouldn't happen at all, should it? Is this issue related with the overheating under workload or is it a separate issue?

Why did prime95 complete all tests without overheating the CPU while a Windows 10 Upgrade manages to overheat the system?

What can I do in order to debug this further?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Update the BIOS/UEFI -Firmware. Maybe replace the fan